# Enable Selection of only two values in SSRS multiple select parameter

Tags: reporting-services

I have a SSRS report in which i have a parameter which comes in a dropdown it is a multiselect parameter, now i want that at most user should be able to select only two values from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are workarounds as suggested by @Kyle Williamson in his answer, but there is no exact answer possible as this facility is not present in SSRS

Answer (score 2):

Although you can't stop the user from selecting more than two values, you can keep the report from being shown if they do.  First, I created a red-text textbox at the top of my report that holds an error message. Something like:

> You selected more than two values for ReportParameter1, try again...

Then, I set the visibility of this message with an expression (for hidden) set to `=(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Count<=2)`.  Now this error will show only when the user has selected more than two parameters.

I then hide the *content* of my report with a visibility expression of `=(Parameters!ReportParameter1.Count>2)`.  Note that you can simply put all your *content* in a rectangle and then hide the rectangle.

If your user selects more than two parameters, only the red error message is shown.  If they select two or less, everything looks normal.  I would also write your stored procedure in a way so that if a user selects too many values for the parameter, it won't return any data.

Comment: the method that you have suggested is a good workaround and i have already implemented the same, but i was looking for something which could disable other values of parameter after two values are selected and "select All" option should always be disabled

Comment: Unfortunately, as @iamdave stated, you cannot currently change the way a multi-select parameters works.  There is currently no way to disable the "select all" option.  This is all built in to the way reporting services work.  I think iamdave's workaround would be the best option for you if you are going to have exactly two values for your parameter or my version for other cases.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  A multi-select parameter is that and just that:  a parameter that lets you select multiple values.

If you will *always* only have two values that need selecting, the easiest way of implementing this would be to have two single value parameters labelled as `Value 1` and `Value 2` which are then both referenced in your report query.